# For Loop on csv file Python

Tags: python, csv, row

I'm writing a program that runs over a csv file and need to check if one of the lines in the csv file equals to the string iv'e decided but it is not working.

```
import csv
f= open('myfile.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
x = 'www.google.com'
for row in csv_f:
    if row[index] == x :
        print "a"
    else:
        print row
```

Comment: Where is you `index` variable declared?

Comment: Why isn't it working? What are the errors etc?

Comment: i need to declare index how can i do it?

Comment: Well what `index` do you want to use?!

Comment: A row contains multiple cells. A typical row might look like `First Cell, 2nd cell, 3rd cell`. Your `x` looks like it's a single cell - which would be at a certain index inside each line. That's the meaning of the `index`.

Answer (score 1):

What is `index`? You want to check first value for equality, or iterate over each value in row? PS. You should close file at the end, or, better, use `with` statement.

```
with open(filename) as f:
    csv_file = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csv_file:
        ...
```